# Why are the drops so large on a water simulation?

Tags: animation

I'm trying to make a waterfall, but the water turns out too big compared to a human. Why are the drops so large? What am I doing wrong? I tried to change the value Resolution but more than 300 Blender crashes. Please help!
[image]

Comment: Make your domain a lot bigger. I believe the size of the domain and the scale size go hand in hand.

Comment: It will be pretty much impossible to pull that off without a higher resolution. Unfortunately the only answer may be to get a better computer. The fluid physics sim is not meant to be used for large areas like this, but for things like a cup of water, etc.

Comment: Did you​ try making your domain bigger?

Comment: Yeah, now I tried to increase the domain but water became even larger: http://i056.radikal.ru/1704/79/47a7d4491eb1.png

Answer (score 2):

You can consider the 'domain' to be made up of a 3-dimensional grid of cells. Each cell is a cube and Blender calculates the properties (density of fluid, motion of fluid, etc.) for each cell.

The Resolution setting indicates how many 'cells' should be included in the simulation - effectively the number of cells along the longest edge of the domain.

So, for a domain in the shape of a cube and with Resolution set to 300 you would have a grid of 300 x 300 x 300 cells - ie, 27 million individual cells!

Most Blender crashes are actually due to running out of memory - when you perform some action (such as setting the Resolution for a fluid simulation, the number of Sub-division Surface divisions, the Remesh detail, or whatever) that results in Blender requesting a considerable chunk of memory that your computer cannot handle - so it either grinds to a halt or crashes blender (or your computer) completely.

Fluid simulations are a trade-off between cell size and number of cells. Obviously you want small cells so as to get a more accurate simulation but you also want to reduce the number of cells to improve efficiency.

In your particular example, it appears that you have a large cube domain - you can see the water running over the 'floor' of the domain. If you don't actually require the water simulation to include the droplets running over the 'floor' then a simple way to reduce the number of cells will be to shrink your domain to include only the waterfall and sufficient space infront and behind to contain any splashes off the model.

As an example, if you reduce the front-to-back dimension to only 20% of the current size then you'll save 80% of the memory requirement for the simulation. The free memory can then be used by upping the resolution further - which should give you better detail for the liquid. An 80% reduction in one dimension will mean you can get almost double resolution in the same memory (510 instead of only 300).

When baking the fluid simulation, the Bake button shows an indication of the memory required. Changing the resolution will affect this value - if it gets too close to your computer's available memory you may want to reconsider before pressing 'Bake'.

[image: Bake memory requirement]

Also, make sure your fluid domain is set up correctly for the liquid you are trying to emulate and at the correct scale. For example, set the Fluid World Real World Size to match the domain size (the longest dimension) and set the vicsocity - this will affect how the fluid behaves and how the liquid breaks up into droplets.